# Barycentric and projective coordinates

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry, plane-geometry

I have a question: what is the relation between the barycentric and the projective coordinates? Are the first one a particular case of the second?
Thank!

Edit: the setting is the plane, and in particular I am asking if the barycentric coordinates on a triangle are equivalent or similar to the projective coordinates in the plan where the vertex of the triangle are labeled with $[0:0:1],[0:1:0],[1:0:0]$.

Comment: There's a lot of context missing in your question. What is your setting for "barycentric coordinates" and for "projective coordinates", i.e. on what objects are those coordinates defined? And what are you using as the definition of those coordinates in that setting?

Comment: They are both examples of _homogeneous coordinates_, as are trilinear coordinates. Any geometric relationship between them is whatever you chose them to be. After all, the basis for your “projective coordinates” is arbitrary.

Comment: Yes. The line at infinity is $x+y+z=0$.